# Changing the chart type in ASP.net when in a DropDownList SelectedIndex Changed event

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, charts, selectedindexchanged

I have a DropDownList and a chart created in ASP.net.The existing items of it are bar chart and pie chart.

I need to select my chart in to the format which is selected in the DropDownList.
Is there any possible way to do this??Thank you in advance....!

My coding is as follows.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="drpChart" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Height="24px" Width="142px">
                            <asp:ListItem>Bar Chart</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Pie Chart</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>

<asp:Chart ID="Chart2" runat="server" style="margin-left: 40px">
                    <Series>
                        <asp:Series Name="Series1">
                        </asp:Series>
                    </Series>
                    <ChartAreas>
                        <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
                        </asp:ChartArea>
                    </ChartAreas>
                </asp:Chart>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple switch statement will do the trick:

**ASPX:**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="drpChart" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Height="24px"
    Width="142px">
    <asp:ListItem>Bar Chart</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Pie Chart</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList><br />
<asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server">
    <Series>
        <asp:Series Name="Series1">
        </asp:Series>
    </Series>
    <ChartAreas>
        <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
        </asp:ChartArea>
    </ChartAreas>
</asp:Chart>
```

**Code behind:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var employees = new Dictionary<int, string>
        {
            {10, "Product A"},{20, "Product B"},{30, "Product C"}
        };

    foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> employee in employees)
    {
        Chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(employee.Value, employee.Key);
    }

    string chartType = drpChart.SelectedValue;
    switch(chartType)
    {
        case "Bar Chart":
            Chart1.Series[0].ChartType = System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Bar;
            break;
        case "Pie Chart":
            Chart1.Series[0].ChartType = System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Pie;
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work....I don't know what is the error...It gives no error, but also doesn't work

Comment: The code to change the chart type should be in the page load event,outside of if(!Page.Is.PostBack) step through your code and see what's going wrong.If you can't figure it out show me your code behind for the page and I'll help you

Answer (score 3):

Use you code in `DropDownList` event i use the same function

here is my code:

```
protected void Dd_Graph_Selection_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string chartType = Dd_Graph_Selection.SelectedValue;
        switch (chartType)
        {
            case "Column Chart":
                Chart1.Series[0].ChartType = System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Column;
                break;
            case "Pie Chart":
                Chart1.Series[0].ChartType = System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Pie;
                break;
            case "Bar Chart":
                Chart1.Series[0].ChartType = System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Bar;
                break;
            case "BoxPlot Chart":
                Chart1.Series[0].ChartType = System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.BoxPlot;
                break;
            case "Funnel Chart":
                Chart1.Series[0].ChartType = System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Funnel;
                break;
            case "Point Chart":
                Chart1.Series[0].ChartType = System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Point;
                break;
            case "Spilinr Chart":
                Chart1.Series[0].ChartType = System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Spline;
                break;
            case "Bubble Chart":
                Chart1.Series[0].ChartType = System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Bubble;
                break;
        }
    }
```